# Private key of 509 Certificate ends up in my user account instead of All Users

Tags: wcf, certificate

I installed a certificate on the server machine for a WCF service.  It installed in the Local Computer area of the Certificates Manager.  However, when I run the service it says it can't find the Private Key file.  When I locate the Private Key, it is in my user account area.  For the WCF to run (it is running HTTP), it is my understanding that it has to have the private key in the All Users area for permissions.  How can I install the certificate to have the private key in the All Users area instead of my login username area?  The makecert command does not seem to have any setting for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the certificate to the Service Account or the Machine Account.  You can do this by adding a Certificate snap-in to the management console:

1. Start->Run->MMC
2. File-> Add/Remove Snappin
3. Select Certificates, Click Add.
4. Select Service Account, and follow the prompts to select the account your service is running as.

[image]

You should now be able to import the certificate by right clicking on the tree and selecting All Tasks -> Import.